# Interfaz de Usuario se queda congelada en While y label no actualiza (PyQt5)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, while

Antes que nada quiero dejar claro que soy muy muy nuevo en Python y Qt.

Estoy creando una interfaz gráfica mediante PyQt5 en Python 3 para un programa que toma los valores de un sonómetro y los guarda en un Excel. Mi problema viene porque quiero mostrar algunos valores en los labels de forma constante, es decir, que se actualicen cada segundo al ritmo que el sonómetro toma los valores, pero al entrar en el bucle While True el cual lee constantemente los valores del aparato, la interfaz se queda congelada, de modo que no llega a salir nada por los labels.

Necesito ayuda, llevo días dándole vueltas y he intentado hacerlo de mil maneras diferentes pero no avanzo nada. Sé que la solución seguramente se encuentra en el uso de Threads pero no consigo entender su funcionamiento al 100% y no sé cómo implementarlo en mi código. Mi propósito es que el proceso de leer datos se ejecute al darle a un botón pero que puedas pararlo dándole a otro. Adjunto el código en cuestión.

```
while True:          
     y = time.strftime("%X")


     d = datetime.now()
     "{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}".format(d)

     linea = str(sc101.readline()) #Lee linea a linea los datos recibidos del sonòmetre y los guarda en la variable  linea 


     LC1=linea[14:17]+'.'+linea[17]      # introduce el valor LC1
     LA1=linea[19:22]+'.'+linea[22]      # introduce el valor LA1
     LCt=linea[24:27]+'.'+linea[27]      # introduce el valor LCt
     LAt=linea[29:32]+'.'+linea[32]      # introduce el valor LAt
     LAF=linea[34:37]+'.'+linea[37]      # introduce el valor LAF
     LAFmin=linea[39:42]+'.'+linea[42]   # introduce el valor LAFmin
     LAFmax=linea[44:47]+'.'+linea[47]   # introduce el valor LAFmax
     LAS=linea[49:52]+'.'+linea[52]      # introduce el valor LAS
     LASmin=linea[54:57]+'.'+linea[57]   # introduce el valor LSmin
     LASmax=linea[59:62]+'.'+linea[62]   # introduce el valor LSmax
     LCpeak=linea[64:67]+'.'+linea[67]   # introduce el valor LCpeak
     LCF=linea[69:72]+'.'+linea[72]      # introduce el valor LCF
     LCFmin=linea[74:77]+'.'+linea[77]   # introduce el valor LCFmin
     LCFmax=linea[79:82]+'.'+linea[82]   # introduce el valor LCFmax  


     self.LAm_7.setText("="+LC1)       #AQUÍ IMPRIMIRÍA EL VALOR EN EL LABEL
```

Si queréis ver más parte del código voy subiendo más, ya que me he dejado la gran mayoría.

¡¡MUCHAS GRACIAS!!

Answer (score 1):

Una GUI por norma general se basa en un ciclo de eventos o ciclo principal (mainloop) que se encarga de responder a eventos y actualizar/redibujar la interfaz gráfica en si mismo cuando sea necesario. Un evento puede ser desde algo generado por el usuario (click, tecla pulsada, etc) a eventos generados por el propio SO o el gestor de ventanas de turno. Dichos eventos pueden o no requerir que se hagan ciertas cosas cuando se producen. Este ciclo de eventos debe estar siempre activo y  poder iterar frecuentemente para poder mantener la app actualizada.

El problema como creo que intuyes dado que refieres la necesidad de usar un hilo, es que tu ciclo while es un ciclo infinito y por tanto bloqueante. Una vez iniciado se iterará indefinidamente sobre el bloqueando el ciclo de eventos (mainloop) de la aplicación. Esto impide que el mainloop pueda responder a eventos (incluido tu intento de modificar el texto del label) y el redibujado de la GUI, congelando la aplicación indefinidamente.

Nunca debe ejecutarse código bloqueante, es decir, que tarde un tiempo relativamente largo en ejecutarse, directamente en el hilo principal de aplicación. Si necesitas realizar una acción reiteradamente tienes varias posibilidades:

- **Lo que bloquea es realmente el ciclo en si solamente, no lo ejecutado en cada iteración**: si cada iteración tarda muy poco en completarse, sin que quepa la posibilidad de bloquear el mainloop, puedes remplazar el ciclo con un temporizador (`QTimer`) y llamar a un método cada x tiempo, encargado de obtener los nuevos datos y actualizar los elementos necesarios de la interfaz en función a ellos:

  ```
  import time
  from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets



  class App(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
      def __init__(self):
          super().__init__()
          self.setWindowTitle("Implementación mediante hilo")
          self.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 300)

          self.boton_iniciar = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Iniciar', self)
          self.boton_iniciar.move(150, 150) 
          self.boton_iniciar.clicked.connect(self.read_data)

          self.label_data = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
          self.label_data.setGeometry(160, 80,  400, 50)
          self.label_data.setText('En espera')

          self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
          self.timer.setInterval(1000) # cada 1000 ms / 1 segundo
          self.timer.timeout.connect(self.read_data_from_sensor)

      @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
      def read_data(self):
          """Iniciar/detener lectura al pulsar el botón"""
          print("gogogo")
          if not self.timer.isActive():
              print("ini")
              self.timer.start()
              self.boton_iniciar.setText("Detener")
          else:
              self.timer.stop()
              self.boton_iniciar.setText("Iniciar")
              self.label_data.setText("En espera")

      @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
      def read_data_from_sensor(self):
          dt  = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
          self.label_data.setText(dt)



  if __name__ == "__main__":
      import sys
      app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
      ventana = App()
      ventana.show()
      sys.exit(app.exec_())
  ```
- **El código ejecutado en cada iteración del ciclo es bloqueante en si mismo:** si cada iteración tarda en completarse o realiza alguna operación que eventualmente sea bloqueante (por ejemplo lectura bloqueante desde socket, puerto serie, etc que quede esperando indefinidamente a que lleguen nuevos datos), lo anterior no nos vale. En este caso deberemos mover dicha operación a un hilo o proceso externo (o usar métodos asíncronos para las operaciones I/O como el uso de corrutinas/asyncio). Por ejemplo, usando un hilo:

  ```
  import time
  from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets



  class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
      started = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
      finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
      data = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
          self.running = False

      @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
      def read_data_from_sensor(self):
          self.started.emit()
          while self.running:
              dt  = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
              self.data.emit(dt)
              time.sleep(3) # Simulamos proceso bloqueante
          self.finished.emit()


  class App(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
      def __init__(self):
          super().__init__()
          self.setWindowTitle("Implementación mediante hilo")
          self.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 300)

          self.boton_iniciar = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Iniciar', self)
          self.boton_iniciar.move(150, 150) 
          self.boton_iniciar.clicked.connect(self.read_data)

          self.label_data = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
          self.label_data.setGeometry(160, 80,  400, 50)
          self.label_data.setText('En espera')

          self._worker = Worker()
          self._worker.started.connect(self.on_started)
          self._worker.finished.connect(self.on_finished)
          self._worker.data.connect(self.update_label)

          self._thread = QtCore.QThread(self)
          self._thread.start()
          self._worker.moveToThread(self._thread)

      @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
      def on_started(self):
          """Será llamada cuando se inicie la recoleccion de datos"""
          self.label_data.setText("Iniciando lectura")
          self.boton_iniciar.setText("Detener")
          self.boton_iniciar.setEnabled(True)

      @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
      def on_finished(self):
          """Será llamada cuando finalize la recolección de datos"""
          self.label_data.setText("En espera")
          self.boton_iniciar.setText("Iniciar")
          self.boton_iniciar.setEnabled(True)

      @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
      def read_data(self):
          """Iniciar/detener lectura al pulsar el botón"""
          if self._worker.running:
              self._worker.running = False
          else:
              self._worker.running = True
              QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self._worker.read_data_from_sensor)
          self.boton_iniciar.setEnabled(False)

      @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
      def update_label(self, data):
          """Será llamada cuando existan nuevos datos a mostrar en el label"""
          self.label_data.setText(data)



  if __name__ == "__main__":
      import sys
      app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
      ventana = App()
      ventana.show()
      sys.exit(app.exec_())
  ```